# Tutorial links for implementing facebook login button

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Hello friend
Please suggest me some links for implementing facebook login button

Answer (score 1):

Try the fb connect module.

http://drupal.org/project/fbconnect

Answer (score 0):

with this module you can link easily your drupal installation with your facebook application
http://www.drupalforfacebook.org